# "Histogram-like" graph

Tags: plot, histogram, stata

I have a dataset made as follows:

```
norm_year   annualsaleswwsales
0   567.9555
1   799.0374
2   940.2049
3   1078.865
4   1242.016
5   1414.186
6   1515.54
7   1641.781
8   1637.157
9   1690.494
10  1616.352
11  1134.324
12  1056.123
13  919.7526
14  642.4491
```

I would like to do a histogram-like plot in Stata where on the y-axis I have annual sales instead of frequency and on the x-axis the normalized year. Ideally, the bins should be transparent and a line should connect each pick of the histogram.

How can I do so?

Comment: `help twoway bar`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A connecting line seems to me over the top in more ways than one, but here is some technique.

```
clear 
input norm_year   annualsaleswwsales
0   567.9555
1   799.0374
2   940.2049
3   1078.865
4   1242.016
5   1414.186
6   1515.54
7   1641.781
8   1637.157
9   1690.494
10  1616.352
11  1134.324
12  1056.123
13  919.7526
14  642.4491
end 

twoway bar annualsaleswwsales norm_year, fc(none) xla(0/14) base(0) yla(0(200)1600)
```

[image]